# SharePoint 2016 search is crawled but not showing the search result

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search

I have restored all four search application-related databases and I could see the crawled content source history, however, whenever I search something in the search site, the search does not give any results and it doesn't give any error as well. Any suggestion on what are the troubleshootings I should check?

Note: This is an old search application that has been running for over two years, all of a sudden after installing the security update, the problem has been started. Then the search schema page was throwing an error, once I have run the SharePoint configuration wizard, the schema page error went.

Comment: What was the reason to restore search application-related databases? Was it part of the Security upgrade? Have you verified if the new contents crawling successfully? You could check by using URL view for individual items. Also, does the search service application look [healthy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spenterprisesearchstatus?view=sharepoint-ps). Also, create a new site collection, add some content, create new search content source and start full crawl. Does the items in the new site collection return in search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to help other folks in the community, how I have fixed this issue. I have run the SharePoint configuration wizard successfully both in APP and WFE server then did the reset index of the search and followed by the Full Crawl.

Note:

- While running the SharePoint configuration wizard, you might get the database version mismatch, for this, we need to upgrade the said databases mentioned in the error log.

Comment: You could mark your reply as answer to help others who meet the similar issue,thank you for your sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Reset the search index and run full crawl to compare the result.

In addition, please make sure the account you search have permissions to sites' contents.